# Getting -1 value from database

Tags: c#

I am making a Login Page. For that i am going to do authenticate the username and password from database. As i execute the program query will run and it return a -1 value. As the username and password is correct. Please Help me out. My program code is as Follow:

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection objcon;
    String query;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    int num;
    //SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//db open in page load.
    {
        objcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source String");
        objcon.Open();
    }
    //query execution and authentication on button click 

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        query = "select * from tbl_user where UserName='" + txtUname.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPwd.Text + "'";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query,objcon);

        num = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Label3.Text = num.ToString();
        if (num == -1)
            Label3.Text = "Correct";
        else
            Label3.Text = "Incorrect";
        objcon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code is very vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: also you should never store user passwords unhashed.

Comment: what's your url? [hehe - inspired by first 2 comments]

Comment: Please read this before you put anything into production.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx  And then go visit the OWASP website, and go through their top 10. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010

Comment: Better yet, don't build your own login mechanism.  ASP.NET has built-in functionality for that, and even experienced developers get it wrong.  The way you're doing it is leaving it open for anyone who would care to google "how to perform an SQL injection" to steal all your database info, put your customers at risk, and if your server is configured incorrectly, allow them to take over the server entirely.  It's the textbook definition of OWASP Top 10 2010-A3-Broken Authentication and Session Management in addition to SQL injection https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3

Answer (score 5):

Look at this code:

```
num = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now given that you're creating a command based on a variable called `query`, do you really think calling a method with the phrase *non-query* in it makes sense? From the docs for [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx), if you're not convinced yet:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. [...] For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

Your statement is a `SELECT` query, so it's returning -1 exactly as documented.

I suspect you should be using [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) or [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx). For example, if you're trying to get the *number* of matches, you should use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ... (rest of query, parameterized of course)
```

Personally I prefer that over taking -1 or null as per James's answer, but it's a matter of taste.

If you're not trying to get the count of matches, it's not clear why you're assigning to an `int` variable in the first place.

EDIT: Additional issues: (*As already mentioned in comments*)

- Only create and open the `SqlConnection` when you need to, not in the constructor
- Use `using` directives for both the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to they're closed even when there's an exception
- **Don't include user input directly in SQL** - use parameterized SQL instead, to SQL avoid injection attacks, improve code/data separation, and avoid conversion errors
- **Don't store your users' password directly in the database in plaintext** - that's a really *horrible* thing for any web site to do.
- **Don't try to write your own user authentication code in the first place** - it's been done for you already, in many different places

Comment: @JamesJohnson: Well, that and writing the answer 5 minutes before you, I suspect... (Have edited for a bit more clarity though.) I don't think it was *really* just for being me. Unless you're suggesting my answer is incorrect?

Comment: As i studied if i got the correct combination it will return the 1. Thats why i use the int num. I cannot want to count the record. I simply want that the User name and password which are entered in the text boxes are in the databases or not. if yes then it will return correct otherwise it will return Incorrect.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It wasn't said maliciously, and I hope you didn't interpret it that way. It's just that such simple questions usually get very little attention, and therefore very few votes. Your celebrity seems to attract a large number of votes though, and I just find it a bit amusing.

Comment: @JonSkeet your answer is correct, but you should notice people upvote you quite a lot more than a typical correct (and first) answer.

Comment: @AsimJawaid: Why would it return 1? From the documentation: "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. [...]  For all other types of statements, the return value is -1." So, do you think your statement is an UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE statement? It sounds like you *do* want to count the records...

Comment: @payo: Note that Daniel's *comment* has received 4 votes... I suspect that if Daniel had posted the same answer as I did, those 4 comment votes would have been answer votes. I dare say there's *some* aspect of the poster identity being involved, but I dispute the idea that all those votes are *just* due to it being my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The quality of your answer is great and by all means worthy of however many upvotes it garners. That being said, you have a lot of fans (myself included) and your answers get a lot of attention. It's a good thing and something you should enjoy, because you've certainly earned it! You've answered 20k+ questions on this site, which is nothing short of remarkable.

Comment: @JonSkeet All? absolutely not. :)

Comment: I also agree with the JonSkeet. Please help me out with the code correction. I studied the ExecuteNonQuery() it will return -1 if i do this. This is my first at any website and i am new user.

Comment: @AsimJawaid: Well I've made various suggestions already - I'm not going to just give you the code, but you should study those suggestions, read up on parameterized SQL etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Using `COUNT` is actually better. Even better yet, just cast the `COUNT` to bit and return a boolean: `CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIT)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to execute a scalar query, meaning that it returns a single value. In the case of your query, if the username and password match, simply select `-1`:

```
SELECT -1 FROM tblUser WHERE Username = 'James' AND Password = 'Johnson'
```

If a value is returned, that value will be `-1` and you know you have a match. If no value (`null`) is returned it didn't match.

**EDIT**

Aside from just answering your question, there are some major problems with your code that you need to address:

1. You're opening a new connection each time the page loads. That's a big no-no! Not only are you opening a new connection on each page load, but you're also not closing the connection once the query has executed.
2. Instead of using concatenation to build your query, use a parameterized query to avoid the risk of SQL injection. Someone with even a little knowledge of SQL could easily escape your query and wreak havoc on your data.